# What can modules provide us that functions can't in python?

Tags: python, module

For example I have a module names `my_mod.py` and the code is:-

```py
def get_sum(int1, int2):
  a = int(int1) + int(int2)
  print(a)
```

And I have the same function in the python file. `my_python_file.py`:-

```py
def get_sum(int1, int2):
  a = int(int1) + int(int2)
  print(a)

get_sum(12, 43)
```

So what is the main difference between modules and functions? Not talking about my example code.
**Main Question:-**
Can anyone give me an example about what can modules do that functions can't?

**Thank you!**

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html might help.

Comment: @Guy thanks for link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules are libraries of function(s).

A module is a file.

```
my_mod.py
```

A function is a code.

```
my_func()
```

You import a module.

```
import my_mod
```

From a module you can import a function.

```
from my_mod import my_func
```

You can pass variables in a function, you will not pass a variable in a module.

```
from my_mod import my_func
my_func(myvar)
```

You can install a module (if published here on PIP)

```
pip install my_mod
```

You can not install a function. The function is defined in your module.

```
#my_mod.py

def my_func(myvar):
    return myvar
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: My pleasure :). Think about accepting the answer if that helped!

Comment: Yes I was about to, but it says wait 8 mins.

Answer (score 1):

When you are going to use the same code multiple times in the same script, you make it into a function to reduce redundancy right? Similarly if you are going to use the same code in multiple different scripts, instead of writing the same function again and again in all the scripts, we write it into a module and we can import and use the function whenever needed. This is a simplified explanation based on how you have used modules alone.

Answer (score 1):

I think in general the Idea with modules, is that a person would write a module, (collection of code for other people to access). It is perhaps a collection of related code to be used as a tool.